# Working with index of column instead of column name in T-SQL

Tags: t-sql

Is there a way in T-SQL to select columns with values instead of names.

For example:

```
Select 1,2 from Table
```

instead of

```
Select name_first_column, name_second_column from Table
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: No. You need to supply the column's name. Using their ordinal position would be a terrible idea (and it is why using [`ORDER BY {Ordinal}` is frowned upon](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/06/bad-habits-to-kick-order-by-ordinal)).

Comment: According to relational set theory, the very definition of a relation (table) is both the rows _and the fields_ are not ordered. In other words, the database is free to change this order out from under you. It rarely happens in practice, but there are some cases where a large text column might be moved to the end.